# Can gnunet-0.8.1 (2 yrs old) be used and useful?

Tags: file-sharing, open-source, p2p, network-protocols, peer-to-peer

I've configured and started [gnunet-0.8.1-alt1.M51.1](http://packages.altlinux.org/en/5.1/srpms/gnunet) service on my system (the reason I use a more than 2 years old version is that the system is an old installation of ALTLinux 5.1, and I wanted to use a pre-built package without upgrading the system).

The current version of [gnunet](http://gnunet.org) is [0.9.5a](https://gnunet.org/gnunet095a).

I've run `gnunet-auto-share` on a directory, and also `gnunet-search -L DEBUG GPL` to test whether I can connect to and search the global gnunet.

It has been running for almost a day (24 hours) already, there are no results, and AFAIU no network activity created by gnunet.

Does this mean that I have some problems with the package I have installed or with my configuration, or simply the protocol of gnunet-0.8.1 is outdated, and that's why it doesn't connect to any peers (which use a modern, incompatible protocol)?

(I have turned on `udp`, `tcp`, `nat` transports, and turned off `http` because it caused an error: no library for it as found.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to move to 0.9.5a since the older peers cannot connect to the newer ones, and out of the few peers that are around, the vast majority are running 0.9.5a.

Comment: 0.9* is out of date now too